# Having issues with keybd_event

Tags: c++

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "winuser.h"

using namespace std;

bool disabled;

int main()
{
    disabled = true;
    cout << "Press INSERT to toggle me on/off. Initially, I am disabled." << endl;
    a:
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_INSERT)){
        disabled = false;
    }
    while(disabled == true){
        goto a;
    }
    while(disabled==false){
        while(GetAsyncKeyState(0x51)){
            keybd_event(0x67,0x67,KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is just a simple prog meant to remove the input of Q and send 7 instead.

However, if I open notepad and test this, the results are like q7777777777777777777777q777777777777777777777777777777777q777777777777777777777777q77777777777777

I don't want my keyboard to send q, how can I fix that?

Also how can i create a brief pause like you would if you were holding down a regular key? For instance, if I hold down 'a' right now:

aaaaaaaaaaaaa
There is a brief pause after the first a and then it proceeds to spam it. How can I replicate that?

Comment: From the top of the documentation: *This function has been superseded. Use SendInput instead.* And for replacing Q with 7, just use AutoHotKey. `::Q::7`

Answer (score 0):

To intercept keyboard events use [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) function with `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` argument.

Also, `keybd_event` simulates a key press, but you also need to simulate a key release by calling `keybd_event` the second time with `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP` flag.